# Recover iCloud password on terminal

Tags: icloud, password, recovery

I have a macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, I forgot my iCloud account password and I was trying recover, however apple says that I need 24h to recover my password since I do not have access to my backup email account (I know this sounds strange but the backup account is the account itself). Is it possible to recover faster based on tmp files or other method?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but another way would be to check your Keychain (Applications > Utilities) and see if you might have it saved there. (possibly from entering it on iCloud.com or appleid.apple.com)

Comment: @KevinGrabher When I copy the password to the clipboard, I got a long word and I do not know which part of those word is the real password, if it is the answer.

Comment: That's not your password then (or an encrypted version of it). Try looking at other entries if you have any (search either for apple or for your email-address that is your iCloud username)

Answer (score 1):

Your password will be in Keychain if you have ever signed in to the web site directly.

You're looking for the one that's listed as www.icloud.com(name@email.com) as a Web form password in the iCloud keychain.

None of the other items in Keychain that look like passwords are in fact "the password", they are all encrypted tokens of some sort & probably indecipherable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have my password there.

Comment: Then I doubt it is anywhere on the Mac in user-readable form. That tends to be the whole idea with security… ;) As soon as you get back in, your first task is to set your recovery email to something useful, then as belt & braces, sign in at the iCloud web site, so at least it's in Keychain.